# "Bip bop, bip bop bop" -- does it mean anything?

Tags: word-usage

There's a song by [Paul McCartnety](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqJxQPYTvqY), Bip-Bop, the main idea of which is quite vague, but nevertheless, three sentences are understood:

> Dig your bottom dollar, put it in your hand.
>   Why d'you hide your
>   handbag underneath the stairs? 
>   Put your hair in curlers, gonna see a band.

At least, this is what is heard among the repetitious "Bip bop, bip bop bop" or "Wip wop, wip man wop." What might these mean?

Comment: The same thing as is meant by "dit dit dit dit" and "tit tit tit tit" in the song **Girl**  or "goo goo goo joob" in "I am the Walrus" or "ooooooh la la la" in still another Beatles song. In other words, precious little except it's something to sing some notes to.

Comment: Having a bit of fun with us, are you, Товарищ?

Comment: @P. E. Dant - I swear the fun is mutual, is it not, товарищ? To further your Russian, I'm gladly suggesting the word that most of the Russians make mistakes writing - "помощник" and "piroshki" (for an English speaking person to order them, if you should know what these are. I'd gladly exchange the email addresses if I knew how, within the format of our communication at this site, should you will it. As for me, I would like it.

Comment: I would rather have пельме́ни ... I am hungry, now!

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Ha, we, my son and I have had those for supper - melted butter, ground pepper,  vinegar, dill, parsley - wry bread, salted salo and Russian vodka, of course.

Comment: Mine I prefer with сметана!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Then add a touch of salt, garlic, pepper, and one-third of kefir (sour milk) into it, I mean сметана)

Comment: Теперь я пускаю слюни!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60869/discussion-between-rompey-and-p-e-dant).

Comment: But they aren't always nonsense syllables though they may seem to be. *Goo Goo Ga Ga Ga* (Talking Heads, *The Big Country*).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Interesting consonantal shift between that and *Doo doo doo da da da* by The Police. I wonder if a plagiarism lawsuit is in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such nonsense syllables are common in English-language folk and popular song.

> Then sigh not so, but let them go,
>     And be you blithe and bonny,
>   Converting all your sounds of woe
>     Into ***hey nonny, nonny***. —‘Much Ado About Nothing’
>
> ***Fa-la-la-la-la, la-la-la-la*** —‘Deck the Halls’
>
> ***Whack fol-de-dah*** now, dance to your partner —‘Finnegan's Wake’
>
> Who put the ***bomp*** in the ***bomp bah bomp bah bomp***
>   Who put the ***ram*** in the ***rama lama ding dong***
>   Who put the ***bop*** in the ***bop shoo bop shoo bop***
>   Who put the ***dip*** in the ***dip da dip da dip*** —‘Who Put the Bomp’
>
> There she was just a-walkin' down the street
>   singin' ***do-wah diddy-diddy down diddy-do*** —‘Do Wah Diddy’

Such phrases often express an exuberance beyond mere linguistic content.

Answer (score 2):

They are not meaningful in common English and I highly doubt they are meaningful in some kind of slang. These kinds of nonsense "words" are sometimes employed for musical effect. There is even a genre called *doo-wop* that's characterized by such usage. From Wikipedia,

> [Doo-wop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doo-wop) is a genre of music that was developed in African-American communities of New York City, Philadelphia, Chicago, Baltimore, Newark, Pittsburgh, Cincinnati, Detroit, Washington, D.C. and Los Angeles in the 1940s, achieving mainstream popularity in the 1950s and early 1960s. [...] Doo-wop features vocal group harmony, nonsense syllables, a simple beat, sometimes little or no instrumentation, and simple music and lyrics.